# Attaching jQuery plugin to dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, append

I'm using a plugin to manage my uploaders. But the problem is that I'm adding new file uploaders every time you hit a button, so the plugin only loads on the element that it's already created when the page loads. This is an example of what I have:

```
<div id="uploaders">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="file-uploader">
            <input type="files" name="files[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Add new uploader</button>
</div>
<script src="js/file-uploader.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $uploaders = $('#uploaders');
    $uploaders.find('.file-uploader input').myPlugin({ options }).on('uploadfinished', function(){ console.log('File uploaded!'); });
    $uploaders.find('button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.container').append('<div class="file-uploader"><input type="files" name="files[]"></div>'); //This uploader won't load myPlugin
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way I could attach that plugin to all the generated file uploaders? I know I could do it right before I append the HTML, but it'd be a problem because I'd have to define again all the configuration and events...

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery .on() method and use the "delegated events" method described here: http://api.jquery.com/on/